# NASM append to string with memory immediately after

Tags: string, assembly, memory-management, x86-64, nasm

For context I'm using NASM on a 64 bit Debian distro.

I'm still learning Assembly as part of writing my own programming language but I recently ran into a problem that I'm not sure how to handle. The following is a snippet of code that my compiler spits out:

```
section .text
global _start
section .var_1 write
    char_1 db 'Q', 0
section .var_2 write
    string_1 db 'Asdf', 0
section .var_3 write
    char_2 db 'W', 0
section .text
_start:
push 4 ; String length onto stack
push string_1
;; Push a raw char onto the stack
mov bl, [char_1]
push bx
pop ax
pop rbx
pop rcx
mov byte [rbx+rcx], al
```

If I then print out the value of `string_1`, I see `AsdfWQ`. As I understand it, this is because of the `mov` command I am using to append combined with the fact that I have some data declared after the string's termination character. I've been trying to search around on Google with no luck about how to resolve this problem (partially because I don't know exactly what to search for). Conceptually I would think I could move the address of everything after `string_1` by the offset of the length of what I'm appending but this seems highly inefficient if I had something like 40 different pieces of data after that. So what I'm trying to sort out is, how do I manage dynamic data that could increase or decrease in size in assembly?

---

**Edit**

Courtesy of fuz pointing out that dynamic memory allocation via the `brk` calls works, I've revised the program a little but am still experience come issues:

```
section .var_1 write                                                                                                                                                                           
    hello_string db '', 0                                                                                                                                                                      
section .var_2 write                                                                                                                                                                           
    again_string db 'Again!', 0                                                                                                                                                                
section .text                                                                                                                                                                                  
    _start:                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Get current break address                                                                                                                                                               
    mov rdi, 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mov rax, 12                                                                                                                                                                                
    syscall                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Attempt to allocate 8 bytes for string                                                                                                                                                  
    mov rdi, rax                                                                                                                                                                               
    add rdi, 8                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mov rax, 12                                                                                                                                                                                
    syscall                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Set the memory address to some label                                                                                                                                                    
    mov qword [hello_string], rax                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Try declaring a string                                                                                                                                                                  
    mov byte [hello_string], 'H'                                                                                                                                                               
    mov byte [hello_string+1], 'e'                                                                                                                                                             
    mov byte [hello_string+2], 'l'                                                                                                                                                             
    mov byte [hello_string+3], 'l'
    mov byte [hello_string+4], 'o'
    mov byte [hello_string+5], ','
    mov byte [hello_string+6], ' '
    mov byte [hello_string+7], 0
    ;; Print the string
    mov rsi, hello_string
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdx, 8
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
    ;; Print the other string
    mov rsi, again_string
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdx, 5
    mov rdi, 1
    syscall
```

This results in `Hello, ello,` which means that I'm still overwriting data associated with the `again_string` label? But I was under the impression that using `brk` to allocate would do so after the data had been initialized?

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation.  This requires you to implement routines similar to what C's `malloc` and `free` do.

Comment: Are the routines like `malloc` and `free` the system calls for `brk` and `sbrk` in that case? Where it looks like I could specify the block of size for a piece of data? And if so, would the "algorithm" for managing the string be to get the string into the register, deallocate the memory that was originally used, reallocate for a new size, append, then store? The other question I would have then is when I reallocate some memory for this string, will the pointer for the first character of the string be pointing to the new start of the memory?

Comment: No, it's the other way round.  `malloc` and `free` are implemented as library functions that occasionally call `brk` or `sbrk` to allocate and release memory.  As for algorithms, there are many you can use.  Algorithms to allocate memory are called *allocators.* A simple one is the Buddy memory allocator.  Read up on it!

Comment: Apologies for the ignorance here, but when you library functions you are referring to C Library functions right? So if this was strictly in assembly (which is the ultimate goal here) I would still need to use `brk` via the Linux syscall command with the size of data the whole program would need and then start using the allocator to actually give memory addresses to the variables that I want to use?

Comment: Yes, correct.  Though you can call `brk` repeatedly to change the position of the data break.  You don't need to know how much memory you need ahead of time.

Comment: Appreciate all the clarification @fuz. I edited my question a little bit because I'm still experiencing the same problem even dynamically storing the data. Do you have any ideas why that might be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect your code to work.  The `brk` call doesn't make new memory between your strings, it appends to the end of memory.  The usual pattern is to use the current program break as the address of the newly allocated object and to then increase it by the size of the object.  You don't seem to be doing anything like that.  I'm also not sure if you are using `brk` correctly.  The system call differs both from the `brk` and `sbrk` wrapper functions as far as I know.

Comment: I guess I was thinking I could use `brk` to create new memory after my strings, then assign the label to start of that new memory. So I get the current program break, extend it by 8 bytes, then set the first of the 8 bytes to be  the first byte in the `hello_string` label instead of what it was originally. My thinking is that it would let me assign a dynamically long string to a label.

Comment: Labels do not exist at runtime.  You cannot change the location of labels.  If you want to program this way, make `hello_string` a pointer to a string, so you can change where it points to.

Comment: That was the missing piece for me. I set `hello_string` to be a `dq` that pointed to `0` to start. Then I allocated the bytes I needed for my string and pointed `hello_string` to the first character in the newly allocated data. Thank you so much for the help and being patient walking me through this! Did you want to make a formal answer so you can get credit for the question?

Comment: Try to write up an answer yourself!  This is a good exercise to show that you have completely understood the concept and may benefit future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to the user `fuz`, and `Peter Cordes` who, through several comments on a weekend, helped rubber duck debug what was going on and educate me at the same time.

It turns out that not knowing pointers really hurt my understanding here. The way to use `brk` and to assign a piece of data, such as a string, to a label, is to do the following:

```
section .var_1 write                                                                                                                                                                           
    hello_string dq 0                                                                                                                                                                     
section .var_2 write                                                                                                                                                                           
    again_string db 'Again!', 0                                                                                                                                                                
section .text                                                                                                                                                                                  
    _start:                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Get current break address                                                                                                                                                               
    mov rdi, 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mov rax, 12                                                                                                                                                                                
    syscall                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Attempt to allocate 8 bytes for string                                                                                                                                                  
    mov rdi, rax                                                                                                                                                                               
    add rdi, 8                                                                                                                                                                                 
    mov rax, 12                                                                                                                                                                                
    syscall                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ;; Stores the pointer to the newly allocated memory to the label                                                                                                                                                    
    mov qword [hello_string], rax                                                                                                                                                              
            
    ;; Do some logic here

    ;; Load the pointer from hello_string into rax for updating                                                                                                                                                                                   
    mov rax, [hello_string]                                                                                                                                
    mov byte [rax], 'H'                                                                                                                                                               
    mov byte [rax+1], 'e'                                                                                                                                                             
    mov byte [rax+2], 'l'                                                                                                                                                             
    ...
```

Two points to note here. First is that you cannot just do `mov byte [hello_string], 'H'` because that is overwriting the pointer so you have to load the pointer into a register, `rax` in this case, to start modifying the bytes. Second, the type of `hello_string` is a `dq` so it can store the value of the pointer and not truncate any data.

Comment: There's no benefit to putting your variables in separate sections.  (Well, `again_string` could go in `.rodata` if you don't want to modify it, but `hello_string dq 0` can just go in `.data`.)  Section layout is fixed at link time, not something you can modify with `brk`.

Comment: `mov byte [hello_string], 'H'` overwrites the low byte of the pointer with an ASCII character.  Maybe you want `mov dword [rax], 'Hell'` / `mov dword [rax+4], 'o!'` or something to dereference the pointer instead of overwriting it.

Comment: If `hello_string` is meant to be a string with a sequence of bytes wouldn't putting the value of the first byte as an ASCII character be ok to do though? Or are you saying that it should be the decimal value here instead?

Comment: I guess the better question here is, if I use `brk` to declare 8 bytes of data, `rax` points to the start of that right? So am I misunderstanding the fact that when I use `mov byte` I'm setting the first of the eight bytes reserved to `H`?

Comment: `hello_string dq 0` in a read/write section is exactly equivalent to C `static char hello_string[8];` or `static char *hello_string;`; both are 8 bytes.  The way you're using it with  `mov byte [hello_string], 'H'` is storing to that static storage, matching the `char[8]` version, or like `memcpy(&hello_string, my_char, 1)` which would overwrite the pointer instead of dereferencing.  x86 doesn't have memory-indirect data addressing.  So no, you're *not* storing to the space you reserved with `brk`, you're overwriting the static storage where you put the pointer.

Comment: Look at compiler output, both optimized and not: https://godbolt.org/z/cP9r437b4

Comment: *if I use brk to declare 8 bytes of data,* - "declare" implies compile / assemble time.  The call to `brk` happens at run-time, at which point it will *allocate* 8 bytes of data.  *`rax` points to the start of that right?* - Yes, that's why I said to use `[rax]` to access that memory, not `[hello_string]` to access static storage.  From your question, you already know `mov bl, [char_1]` loads that one byte, not taking a qword from there and treating it as a pointer.  (Because that's how NASM syntax works, and because x86 can't do that in one instruction.)

Comment: If you're still not convinced that your current program is broken by using a debugger to look at the 8 bytes at `hello_string`, change the allocation size to 16 or something larger than the size of a pointer.  Then notice that `mov byte [hello_string+8], 'x'` will overwrite the first byte of `again_string`, assuming the linker put those two sections next to each other.  (Using separate sections might disguise the issue; just put them both in `.data` like a compiler would for multiple read/write variables.)  But `mov byte [rax+8], 'x'` will modify the pointed-to memory.

Comment: Ok so I'm starting to understand what you are saying. I just happened to pick a lucky scenario where the data I was modifying was small enough that I couldn't see a bug popping up as a result it seems. So I guess where I'm still confused (and I apologize I'm not a C developer so learning as I go) is if `rax` is a pointer to the 8 bytes of memory, how do I save that pointer to a label so I could update the bytes anywhere in my program? Is that just `mov qword [hello_string], [rax]`?

Comment: No, `mov [hello_string], rax` is the correct way to store the pointer into static storage (like a global variable) where you could load it later.  But you need the pointer in a register to access the pointed-to storage; look at the compiler output I linked, where the un-optimized clang output has to `mov rax, [hello_string]` / `mov byte [rax], 'H'` to use a pointer from memory.  (Godbolt has compilers for lots of languages; pick one you do know that has simple pointer types and an ahead-of-time compiler that can make examples for you.)

Comment: Think I finally had that "a-ha" moment. I didn't know I needed to load the pointer into register first before working with the data. I thought I could just start working with the data. So if I do `mov qword [hello_string], rax` after using `brk` to declare 16 bytes of data, then later in my assembly calling `mov rax, [hello_string]` to update the 16 bytes, then do some other stuff still, and finally when I'm ready to print I reload rax with the pointer via `mov rax, [hello_string]` followed by `mov rsi, rax`, I'm able to print my string. Is there another hidden bug or did I finally get it?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.  Use `mov rsi, [hello_string]` if that's where you want the pointer, e.g. for a `write` system call.

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate the thoroughness and your patience in walking through this and explaining everything.

Comment: Now you're using the return value correctly, but the `brk` system call takes a pointer arg (to set the new break).  On failure it returns the old break, on success it return the new break.  This happens to work for your code because the old break is sufficiently far from the end of a page, and is at least some bytes after the end of the static data that follows `again_string`.  See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html#NOTES .  There is no `sbrk` system call; you have to track the current break yourself if you want to use `brk` instead of `call malloc` or an `mmap` syscall.

Comment: Hmm. Is this assumption correct? When I first call `brk` with the value `0`, that is getting the next available location for "free" memory I could use. Then I'm allocating some number of bytes and putting the pointer to those bytes into `hello_string`. Then I'm doing whatever logic, loading up the pointer that `hello_string` has, then putting data into those bytes. If I wanted to call `brk` again, can I not get tracking for free by loading the pointer in `hello_string` plus the length of the data, 8 bytes in this case, into `rdi`, and then allocating some number of bytes again?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your code.  That's an `add rdi, 8` not `mov`.  I think you are using it correctly, with the first call `brk(NULL)` correctly getting the old break.  I would have used `lea rdi, [rax+8]` instead of mov/add, but your way is correct.  IDK why I was assuming it was wrong before without even reading the comments; I guess I was in a hurry or something.

Comment: I guess I thought it would look more complicated, but it really isn't that much code for a system call that takes only one arg.  And you're not saving the break anywhere for future use, so future allocations are also going to take two system calls instead of one.  (Even one system call is disastrously slow for every time you want to allocate 8 or 16 bytes; that's why `malloc` manages a free list.  But this is fine for toy uses.)

Comment: Sweet. I can optimize the assembly down once I practice with it a little bit and I'll read up on the `lea` instruction as I prepare to optimize the assembly some. Thank you again for all the comments and back and forth. It's been a great learning experience as a result and super helpful.